# htacess redirect has changed subdomain behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After writing a 301 redirect using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/404ErrorPage.htm
```

My domain "www.ai-total-fitness.com" now has the prefix "http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/wsb5841134301/" which although that is where the files are for the website : ai-total-fitness, all the links now point to the other site, I'm guessing this is due the redirect rule, can anyone suggest the correct code to exclude the ai-total-fitness.com site and files please?

The aicolche~ site is in the root folder, and the ai-total-fitness site is within a folder in that directory

Answer (score 0):

To exclude `ai-total-fitness.com`, add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?ai-total-fitness\.com$ [NC]
```

so that it looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?ai-total-fitness\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/404ErrorPage.htm
```

Comment: Many thanks Jon, I tried this and the same thing happens, the ai-total-fitness website still shows up as http://aicolchesterpersonaltrainer.co.uk/wsb5841134301/ and not with the url www.ai-total-fitness.com as it was before I added the 301 redirect

Comment: @Andy did you clear your browser's cache? A 301 redirect is permanent and your browser is going to continue to use the old redirect until its cache is cleared.